# api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll is missing

Tags: dll

Im using widows 7 on my working PC and i know i should update (i have win10 on my common pc)
but i still need to finish some important art projects and updating my system now would cause me a lot of compatibility trouble with some wierd and old programs i use so im stuck with win7 until im done with theses projects.

However, last night i had an update (i thought there was no more updates wor win7 Oo')
and since then, my mouse software wont work anymore !
the software is called "Steelseries Engine"
i worked until late and the software was working, but today, it wont start.

i tried to restart, update, and reinstalling but the problem seems to come from some missing dll.

when i go into the install folder and launch it from there, it gives me the following error :

the program cant start because "**api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll**" is missing.

Anyone could tell me how to repair that ? is it something related to visual c++ or something ?

I really need help, because i have to finish my project fast and witout my mouse setup/macros its going to take ages.
art
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem from yesterday, now.
Same message, same circonstances, "steel series" connected + windows 7, and i see no reason why it started. i reinstalled the steelseries engine exe i kept from my personal depository file, and it worked, then today i rebooted the PC and the dll message came back. Very strange. Stranger is that the steel series engine exe for the mouse and Co is not available for windows 7 anymore ont the steelseries website, it is written "For windows 8 and upper versions."

edit: i fixed the .ddl missing trouble, even though i don't know how it started. Thanks to CCLEANER, i found in the start list a long command line stating that the .dll will be deleted by a steel series operator. Delete this *useless* line (i don't know where it suddenly came from, may be a corrupted auto upgrade by SSeries) and reinstall steelseriesengine. I'm pretty sure this problem had nothing to do with W7. Enjoy.